# GRPC-GW - HTTP service not registering

Tags: go, http, grpc, protobuf-go

trying to create a grpc server with a http gw server. The GRPC server is working as expected on port 8081, I can ping and get a proper response. When I ping the http endpoint (localhost:8082/v1/ums2) I keep getting 501 not implemented. Ive tried to register the service a couple different ways as shown below, but all of them are resulting in the same response, I must be missing something

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

option go_package = "github.com/nable-fusion/msp-sso-proxy/pb";

message TestRequest {
  string foo = 10;
}

message TestResponse {
  string bar = 10;
}

service SSOProxy {
  rpc TestEndpoint(TestRequest) returns (TestResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/ums2"
      body: "*"
    };
  }

  rpc Login(TestRequest) returns (TestResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/login"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}
```

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//  protoc-gen-go v1.31.0
//  protoc        v4.23.4
// source: server.proto

package pb

import (
    _ "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations"
    protoreflect "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    protoimpl "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
    reflect "reflect"
    sync "sync"
)

const (
    // Verify that this generated code is sufficiently up-to-date.
    _ = protoimpl.EnforceVersion(20 - protoimpl.MinVersion)
    // Verify that runtime/protoimpl is sufficiently up-to-date.
    _ = protoimpl.EnforceVersion(protoimpl.MaxVersion - 20)
)

type TestRequest struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Foo string `protobuf:"bytes,10,opt,name=foo,proto3" json:"foo,omitempty"`
}

func (x *TestRequest) Reset() {
    *x = TestRequest{}
    if protoimpl.UnsafeEnabled {
        mi := &file_server_proto_msgTypes[0]
        ms := protoimpl.X.MessageStateOf(protoimpl.Pointer(x))
        ms.StoreMessageInfo(mi)
    }
}

func (x *TestRequest) String() string {
    return protoimpl.X.MessageStringOf(x)
}

func (*TestRequest) ProtoMessage() {}

func (x *TestRequest) ProtoReflect() protoreflect.Message {
    mi := &file_server_proto_msgTypes[0]
    if protoimpl.UnsafeEnabled && x != nil {
        ms := protoimpl.X.MessageStateOf(protoimpl.Pointer(x))
        if ms.LoadMessageInfo() == nil {
            ms.StoreMessageInfo(mi)
        }
        return ms
    }
    return mi.MessageOf(x)
}

// Deprecated: Use TestRequest.ProtoReflect.Descriptor instead.
func (*TestRequest) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return file_server_proto_rawDescGZIP(), []int{0}
}

func (x *TestRequest) GetFoo() string {
    if x != nil {
        return x.Foo
    }
    return ""
}

type TestResponse struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Bar string `protobuf:"bytes,10,opt,name=bar,proto3" json:"bar,omitempty"`
}

func (x *TestResponse) Reset() {
    *x = TestResponse{}
    if protoimpl.UnsafeEnabled {
        mi := &file_server_proto_msgTypes[1]
        ms := protoimpl.X.MessageStateOf(protoimpl.Pointer(x))
        ms.StoreMessageInfo(mi)
    }
}

func (x *TestResponse) String() string {
    return protoimpl.X.MessageStringOf(x)
}

func (*TestResponse) ProtoMessage() {}

func (x *TestResponse) ProtoReflect() protoreflect.Message {
    mi := &file_server_proto_msgTypes[1]
    if protoimpl.UnsafeEnabled && x != nil {
        ms := protoimpl.X.MessageStateOf(protoimpl.Pointer(x))
        if ms.LoadMessageInfo() == nil {
            ms.StoreMessageInfo(mi)
        }
        return ms
    }
    return mi.MessageOf(x)
}

// Deprecated: Use TestResponse.ProtoReflect.Descriptor instead.
func (*TestResponse) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return file_server_proto_rawDescGZIP(), []int{1}
}

func (x *TestResponse) GetBar() string {
    if x != nil {
        return x.Bar
    }
    return ""
}

var File_server_proto protoreflect.FileDescriptor

var file_server_proto_rawDesc = []byte{
    0x0a, 0x0c, 0x73, 0x65, 0x72, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x1a, 0x1c,
    0x67, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x67, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x61, 0x70, 0x69, 0x2f, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x74,
    0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x2e, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x22, 0x1f, 0x0a, 0x0b,
    0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x52, 0x65, 0x71, 0x75, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x12, 0x10, 0x0a, 0x03, 0x66,
    0x6f, 0x6f, 0x18, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x01, 0x28, 0x09, 0x52, 0x03, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x22, 0x20, 0x0a,
    0x0c, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x52, 0x65, 0x73, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x65, 0x12, 0x10, 0x0a,
    0x03, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x18, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x01, 0x28, 0x09, 0x52, 0x03, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x32,
    0x88, 0x01, 0x0a, 0x08, 0x53, 0x53, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x78, 0x79, 0x12, 0x40, 0x0a, 0x0c,
    0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x12, 0x0c, 0x2e, 0x54,
    0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x52, 0x65, 0x71, 0x75, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x1a, 0x0d, 0x2e, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73,
    0x74, 0x52, 0x65, 0x73, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x65, 0x22, 0x13, 0x82, 0xd3, 0xe4, 0x93, 0x02,
    0x0d, 0x3a, 0x01, 0x2a, 0x22, 0x08, 0x2f, 0x76, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x73, 0x32, 0x12, 0x3a,
    0x0a, 0x05, 0x4c, 0x6f, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x12, 0x0c, 0x2e, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x52, 0x65,
    0x71, 0x75, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x1a, 0x0d, 0x2e, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x52, 0x65, 0x73, 0x70,
    0x6f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x65, 0x22, 0x14, 0x82, 0xd3, 0xe4, 0x93, 0x02, 0x0e, 0x3a, 0x01, 0x2a, 0x22,
    0x09, 0x2f, 0x76, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x42, 0x2a, 0x5a, 0x28, 0x67, 0x69,
    0x74, 0x68, 0x75, 0x62, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x2d, 0x66,
    0x75, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x6d, 0x73, 0x70, 0x2d, 0x73, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x2d, 0x70, 0x72,
    0x6f, 0x78, 0x79, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x62, 0x62, 0x06, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x33,
}

var (
    file_server_proto_rawDescOnce sync.Once
    file_server_proto_rawDescData = file_server_proto_rawDesc
)

func file_server_proto_rawDescGZIP() []byte {
    file_server_proto_rawDescOnce.Do(func() {
        file_server_proto_rawDescData = protoimpl.X.CompressGZIP(file_server_proto_rawDescData)
    })
    return file_server_proto_rawDescData
}

var file_server_proto_msgTypes = make([]protoimpl.MessageInfo, 2)
var file_server_proto_goTypes = []interface{}{
    (*TestRequest)(nil),  // 0: TestRequest
    (*TestResponse)(nil), // 1: TestResponse
}
var file_server_proto_depIdxs = []int32{
    0, // 0: SSOProxy.TestEndpoint:input_type -> TestRequest
    0, // 1: SSOProxy.Login:input_type -> TestRequest
    1, // 2: SSOProxy.TestEndpoint:output_type -> TestResponse
    1, // 3: SSOProxy.Login:output_type -> TestResponse
    2, // [2:4] is the sub-list for method output_type
    0, // [0:2] is the sub-list for method input_type
    0, // [0:0] is the sub-list for extension type_name
    0, // [0:0] is the sub-list for extension extendee
    0, // [0:0] is the sub-list for field type_name
}

func init() { file_server_proto_init() }
func file_server_proto_init() {
    if File_server_proto != nil {
        return
    }
    if !protoimpl.UnsafeEnabled {
        file_server_proto_msgTypes[0].Exporter = func(v interface{}, i int) interface{} {
            switch v := v.(*TestRequest); i {
            case 0:
                return &v.state
            case 1:
                return &v.sizeCache
            case 2:
                return &v.unknownFields
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        file_server_proto_msgTypes[1].Exporter = func(v interface{}, i int) interface{} {
            switch v := v.(*TestResponse); i {
            case 0:
                return &v.state
            case 1:
                return &v.sizeCache
            case 2:
                return &v.unknownFields
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    type x struct{}
    out := protoimpl.TypeBuilder{
        File: protoimpl.DescBuilder{
            GoPackagePath: reflect.TypeOf(x{}).PkgPath(),
            RawDescriptor: file_server_proto_rawDesc,
            NumEnums:      0,
            NumMessages:   2,
            NumExtensions: 0,
            NumServices:   1,
        },
        GoTypes:           file_server_proto_goTypes,
        DependencyIndexes: file_server_proto_depIdxs,
        MessageInfos:      file_server_proto_msgTypes,
    }.Build()
    File_server_proto = out.File
    file_server_proto_rawDesc = nil
    file_server_proto_goTypes = nil
    file_server_proto_depIdxs = nil
}
```

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-grpc-gateway. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: server.proto

/*
Package pb is a reverse proxy.

It translates gRPC into RESTful JSON APIs.
*/
package pb

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/utilities"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/grpclog"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

// Suppress "imported and not used" errors
var _ codes.Code
var _ io.Reader
var _ status.Status
var _ = runtime.String
var _ = utilities.NewDoubleArray
var _ = metadata.Join

func request_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(ctx context.Context, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, client SSOProxyClient, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) (proto.Message, runtime.ServerMetadata, error) {
    var protoReq TestRequest
    var metadata runtime.ServerMetadata

    newReader, berr := utilities.IOReaderFactory(req.Body)
    if berr != nil {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", berr)
    }
    if err := marshaler.NewDecoder(newReader()).Decode(&protoReq); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", err)
    }

    msg, err := client.TestEndpoint(ctx, &protoReq, grpc.Header(&metadata.HeaderMD), grpc.Trailer(&metadata.TrailerMD))
    return msg, metadata, err

}

func local_request_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(ctx context.Context, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, server SSOProxyServer, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) (proto.Message, runtime.ServerMetadata, error) {
    var protoReq TestRequest
    var metadata runtime.ServerMetadata

    newReader, berr := utilities.IOReaderFactory(req.Body)
    if berr != nil {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", berr)
    }
    if err := marshaler.NewDecoder(newReader()).Decode(&protoReq); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", err)
    }

    msg, err := server.TestEndpoint(ctx, &protoReq)
    return msg, metadata, err

}

func request_SSOProxy_Login_0(ctx context.Context, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, client SSOProxyClient, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) (proto.Message, runtime.ServerMetadata, error) {
    var protoReq TestRequest
    var metadata runtime.ServerMetadata

    newReader, berr := utilities.IOReaderFactory(req.Body)
    if berr != nil {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", berr)
    }
    if err := marshaler.NewDecoder(newReader()).Decode(&protoReq); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", err)
    }

    msg, err := client.Login(ctx, &protoReq, grpc.Header(&metadata.HeaderMD), grpc.Trailer(&metadata.TrailerMD))
    return msg, metadata, err

}

func local_request_SSOProxy_Login_0(ctx context.Context, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, server SSOProxyServer, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) (proto.Message, runtime.ServerMetadata, error) {
    var protoReq TestRequest
    var metadata runtime.ServerMetadata

    newReader, berr := utilities.IOReaderFactory(req.Body)
    if berr != nil {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", berr)
    }
    if err := marshaler.NewDecoder(newReader()).Decode(&protoReq); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return nil, metadata, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "%v", err)
    }

    msg, err := server.Login(ctx, &protoReq)
    return msg, metadata, err

}

// RegisterSSOProxyHandlerServer registers the http handlers for service SSOProxy to "mux".
// UnaryRPC     :call SSOProxyServer directly.
// StreamingRPC :currently unsupported pending https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/906.
// Note that using this registration option will cause many gRPC library features to stop working. Consider using RegisterSSOProxyHandlerFromEndpoint instead.
func RegisterSSOProxyHandlerServer(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, server SSOProxyServer) error {

    mux.Handle("POST", pattern_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0, func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(req.Context())
        defer cancel()
        var stream runtime.ServerTransportStream
        ctx = grpc.NewContextWithServerTransportStream(ctx, &stream)
        inboundMarshaler, outboundMarshaler := runtime.MarshalerForRequest(mux, req)
        var err error
        var annotatedContext context.Context
        annotatedContext, err = runtime.AnnotateIncomingContext(ctx, mux, req, "/.SSOProxy/TestEndpoint", runtime.WithHTTPPathPattern("/v1/ums2"))
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(ctx, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }
        resp, md, err := local_request_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(annotatedContext, inboundMarshaler, server, req, pathParams)
        md.HeaderMD, md.TrailerMD = metadata.Join(md.HeaderMD, stream.Header()), metadata.Join(md.TrailerMD, stream.Trailer())
        annotatedContext = runtime.NewServerMetadataContext(annotatedContext, md)
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }

        forward_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, resp, mux.GetForwardResponseOptions()...)

    })

    mux.Handle("POST", pattern_SSOProxy_Login_0, func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(req.Context())
        defer cancel()
        var stream runtime.ServerTransportStream
        ctx = grpc.NewContextWithServerTransportStream(ctx, &stream)
        inboundMarshaler, outboundMarshaler := runtime.MarshalerForRequest(mux, req)
        var err error
        var annotatedContext context.Context
        annotatedContext, err = runtime.AnnotateIncomingContext(ctx, mux, req, "/.SSOProxy/Login", runtime.WithHTTPPathPattern("/v1/login"))
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(ctx, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }
        resp, md, err := local_request_SSOProxy_Login_0(annotatedContext, inboundMarshaler, server, req, pathParams)
        md.HeaderMD, md.TrailerMD = metadata.Join(md.HeaderMD, stream.Header()), metadata.Join(md.TrailerMD, stream.Trailer())
        annotatedContext = runtime.NewServerMetadataContext(annotatedContext, md)
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }

        forward_SSOProxy_Login_0(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, resp, mux.GetForwardResponseOptions()...)

    })

    return nil
}

// RegisterSSOProxyHandlerFromEndpoint is same as RegisterSSOProxyHandler but
// automatically dials to "endpoint" and closes the connection when "ctx" gets done.
func RegisterSSOProxyHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, endpoint string, opts []grpc.DialOption) (err error) {
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, endpoint, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            if cerr := conn.Close(); cerr != nil {
                grpclog.Infof("Failed to close conn to %s: %v", endpoint, cerr)
            }
            return
        }
        go func() {
            <-ctx.Done()
            if cerr := conn.Close(); cerr != nil {
                grpclog.Infof("Failed to close conn to %s: %v", endpoint, cerr)
            }
        }()
    }()

    return RegisterSSOProxyHandler(ctx, mux, conn)
}

// RegisterSSOProxyHandler registers the http handlers for service SSOProxy to "mux".
// The handlers forward requests to the grpc endpoint over "conn".
func RegisterSSOProxyHandler(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, conn *grpc.ClientConn) error {
    return RegisterSSOProxyHandlerClient(ctx, mux, NewSSOProxyClient(conn))
}

// RegisterSSOProxyHandlerClient registers the http handlers for service SSOProxy
// to "mux". The handlers forward requests to the grpc endpoint over the given implementation of "SSOProxyClient".
// Note: the gRPC framework executes interceptors within the gRPC handler. If the passed in "SSOProxyClient"
// doesn't go through the normal gRPC flow (creating a gRPC client etc.) then it will be up to the passed in
// "SSOProxyClient" to call the correct interceptors.
func RegisterSSOProxyHandlerClient(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, client SSOProxyClient) error {

    mux.Handle("POST", pattern_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0, func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(req.Context())
        defer cancel()
        inboundMarshaler, outboundMarshaler := runtime.MarshalerForRequest(mux, req)
        var err error
        var annotatedContext context.Context
        annotatedContext, err = runtime.AnnotateContext(ctx, mux, req, "/.SSOProxy/TestEndpoint", runtime.WithHTTPPathPattern("/v1/ums2"))
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(ctx, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }
        resp, md, err := request_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(annotatedContext, inboundMarshaler, client, req, pathParams)
        annotatedContext = runtime.NewServerMetadataContext(annotatedContext, md)
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }

        forward_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, resp, mux.GetForwardResponseOptions()...)

    })

    mux.Handle("POST", pattern_SSOProxy_Login_0, func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(req.Context())
        defer cancel()
        inboundMarshaler, outboundMarshaler := runtime.MarshalerForRequest(mux, req)
        var err error
        var annotatedContext context.Context
        annotatedContext, err = runtime.AnnotateContext(ctx, mux, req, "/.SSOProxy/Login", runtime.WithHTTPPathPattern("/v1/login"))
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(ctx, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }
        resp, md, err := request_SSOProxy_Login_0(annotatedContext, inboundMarshaler, client, req, pathParams)
        annotatedContext = runtime.NewServerMetadataContext(annotatedContext, md)
        if err != nil {
            runtime.HTTPError(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, err)
            return
        }

        forward_SSOProxy_Login_0(annotatedContext, mux, outboundMarshaler, w, req, resp, mux.GetForwardResponseOptions()...)

    })

    return nil
}

var (
    pattern_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0 = runtime.MustPattern(runtime.NewPattern(1, []int{2, 0, 2, 1}, []string{"v1", "ums2"}, ""))

    pattern_SSOProxy_Login_0 = runtime.MustPattern(runtime.NewPattern(1, []int{2, 0, 2, 1}, []string{"v1", "login"}, ""))
)

var (
    forward_SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_0 = runtime.ForwardResponseMessage

    forward_SSOProxy_Login_0 = runtime.ForwardResponseMessage
)
```

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go-grpc. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
// - protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.3.0
// - protoc             v4.23.4
// source: server.proto

package pb

import (
    context "context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
    codes "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    status "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the grpc package it is being compiled against.
// Requires gRPC-Go v1.32.0 or later.
const _ = grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7

const (
    SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_FullMethodName = "/SSOProxy/TestEndpoint"
    SSOProxy_Login_FullMethodName        = "/SSOProxy/Login"
)

// SSOProxyClient is the client API for SSOProxy service.
//
// For semantics around ctx use and closing/ending streaming RPCs, please refer to https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/?tab=doc#ClientConn.NewStream.
type SSOProxyClient interface {
    TestEndpoint(ctx context.Context, in *TestRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*TestResponse, error)
    Login(ctx context.Context, in *TestRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*TestResponse, error)
}

type sSOProxyClient struct {
    cc grpc.ClientConnInterface
}

func NewSSOProxyClient(cc grpc.ClientConnInterface) SSOProxyClient {
    return &sSOProxyClient{cc}
}

func (c *sSOProxyClient) TestEndpoint(ctx context.Context, in *TestRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*TestResponse, error) {
    out := new(TestResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_FullMethodName, in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

func (c *sSOProxyClient) Login(ctx context.Context, in *TestRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*TestResponse, error) {
    out := new(TestResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, SSOProxy_Login_FullMethodName, in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

// SSOProxyServer is the server API for SSOProxy service.
// All implementations must embed UnimplementedSSOProxyServer
// for forward compatibility
type SSOProxyServer interface {
    TestEndpoint(context.Context, *TestRequest) (*TestResponse, error)
    Login(context.Context, *TestRequest) (*TestResponse, error)
    mustEmbedUnimplementedSSOProxyServer()
}

// UnimplementedSSOProxyServer must be embedded to have forward compatible implementations.
type UnimplementedSSOProxyServer struct {
}

func (UnimplementedSSOProxyServer) TestEndpoint(context.Context, *TestRequest) (*TestResponse, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method TestEndpoint not implemented")
}
func (UnimplementedSSOProxyServer) Login(context.Context, *TestRequest) (*TestResponse, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method Login not implemented")
}
func (UnimplementedSSOProxyServer) mustEmbedUnimplementedSSOProxyServer() {}

// UnsafeSSOProxyServer may be embedded to opt out of forward compatibility for this service.
// Use of this interface is not recommended, as added methods to SSOProxyServer will
// result in compilation errors.
type UnsafeSSOProxyServer interface {
    mustEmbedUnimplementedSSOProxyServer()
}

func RegisterSSOProxyServer(s grpc.ServiceRegistrar, srv SSOProxyServer) {
    s.RegisterService(&SSOProxy_ServiceDesc, srv)
}

func _SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, dec func(interface{}) error, interceptor grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor) (interface{}, error) {
    in := new(TestRequest)
    if err := dec(in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if interceptor == nil {
        return srv.(SSOProxyServer).TestEndpoint(ctx, in)
    }
    info := &grpc.UnaryServerInfo{
        Server:     srv,
        FullMethod: SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_FullMethodName,
    }
    handler := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return srv.(SSOProxyServer).TestEndpoint(ctx, req.(*TestRequest))
    }
    return interceptor(ctx, in, info, handler)
}

func _SSOProxy_Login_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, dec func(interface{}) error, interceptor grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor) (interface{}, error) {
    in := new(TestRequest)
    if err := dec(in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if interceptor == nil {
        return srv.(SSOProxyServer).Login(ctx, in)
    }
    info := &grpc.UnaryServerInfo{
        Server:     srv,
        FullMethod: SSOProxy_Login_FullMethodName,
    }
    handler := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return srv.(SSOProxyServer).Login(ctx, req.(*TestRequest))
    }
    return interceptor(ctx, in, info, handler)
}

// SSOProxy_ServiceDesc is the grpc.ServiceDesc for SSOProxy service.
// It's only intended for direct use with grpc.RegisterService,
// and not to be introspected or modified (even as a copy)
var SSOProxy_ServiceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "SSOProxy",
    HandlerType: (*SSOProxyServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "TestEndpoint",
            Handler:    _SSOProxy_TestEndpoint_Handler,
        },
        {
            MethodName: "Login",
            Handler:    _SSOProxy_Login_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams:  []grpc.StreamDesc{},
    Metadata: "server.proto",
}
```

```
package gw_server

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/nable-fusion/msp-sso-proxy/pb"
)

type sSOProxyServerImpl struct {
    pb.SSOProxyServer
}

func newSSOProxyServerImpl() *sSOProxyServerImpl {
    return &sSOProxyServerImpl{}
}

func (s *sSOProxyServerImpl) TestEndpoint(ctx context.Context, request *pb.TestRequest) (*pb.TestResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println("request is: " + request.Foo)
    return &pb.TestResponse{Bar: "123"}, nil
}

func (s *sSOProxyServerImpl) Login(ctx context.Context, request *pb.TestRequest) (*pb.TestResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println("request is: " + request.Foo)
    return &pb.TestResponse{Bar: "1234"}, nil
}
```

```
package gw_server

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
    "github.com/nable-fusion/fusion-cloud-common/pkg/log"
    pb "github.com/nable-fusion/msp-sso-proxy/pb"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

func RunGrpcServer() {
    go runGrpcServer()
    runGatewayServer()
}

func runGrpcServer() {
    log := log.NewLogger(log.NewConfig())
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterSSOProxyServer(grpcServer, newSSOProxyServerImpl())
    reflection.Register(grpcServer)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8081")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot create listener", zap.Error(err))
    }

    log.Info("start gRPC server at %s", zap.String("asdf", listener.Addr().String()))
    err = grpcServer.Serve(listener)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("cannot start gRPC server", zap.Error(err))
    }
}

func runGatewayServer() {

    log := log.NewLogger(log.NewConfig())

    grpcMux := runtime.NewServeMux()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:8081", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Failed to dial server:", zap.Error(err))
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    //Register way #1
    err = pb.RegisterSSOProxyHandler(ctx, grpcMux, conn)

    //Register way #2
    //err := pb.RegisterSSOProxyHandlerServer(ctx, grpcMux, newSSOProxyServerImpl())

    //Register way #3
    //grpcServerEndpoint := flag.String("grpc-server-endpoint", "localhost:8082", "gRPC server endpoint")
    //err := pb.RegisterSSOProxyHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, grpcMux, *grpcServerEndpoint, []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())})

    if err != nil {
        log.Error("cannot register handler server", zap.Error(err))
    }

    //mux := http.NewServeMux()
    //mux.Handle("/", grpcMux)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8082")
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("cannot create listener", zap.Error(err))
    }

    log.Info("start HTTP gateway server at %s", zap.String("asdf", listener.Addr().String()))
    err = http.Serve(listener, grpcMux)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("cannot start HTTP gateway server", zap.Error(err))
    }
}
```

Ive tried 3 different ways to register the handlers to convert http, but none of them seem to help. The grpc server is working normally, so I must just not be registering the http server correctly

Comment: Kudos for such a clearly-worded and comprehensive question!

Comment: Your code works as-is for me.

Comment: As expected: `curl --request POST -d '{}' localhost:8082/v1/login` returns `{"bar":"1234"}` and `curl --request POST -d '{}' localhost:8082/v1/ums2` returns `{"bar":"123"}`

Comment: SMH, yes it's working as is, my issue was I was trying to make a GET request as opposed to a POST request. TY!